# How can we store airbyte connectors configuartion data?

Tags: connection

Need to store the airbyte - connectors , sources & destinations configurations data as a backup .
Had an approach to use Octavia , but facing issue while downloading data for specific connection.

like this :

octavia import connection [connection-ID]

error: TypeError: _from_openapi_data() missing 3 required positional arguments: ‘schema_change’, ‘notify_schema_changes’, and ‘non_breaking_changes_preference’
Is there a version issue or any other

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the version to Octavia 0.40.18

```
curl -s -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airbytehq/airbyte/v0.40.18/octavia-cli/install.sh | bash
```

```
alias octavia="docker run -i --rm -v \$(pwd):/home/octavia-project --network host --env-file \${OCTAVIA_ENV_FILE} --user \$(id -u):\$(id -g) airbyte/octavia-cli:0.40.18"
```

and added these variables to .octavia file.

```
nano ~/.octavia
```

```
OCTAVIA_ENABLE_TELEMETRY=True
AIRBYTE_USERNAME=airbyte
AIRBYTE_PASSWORD=password
```

& used all octavia commands.

```
mkdir airbyte-configs-data && cd airbyte-configs-data
```

```
octavia init
octavia import all
```

and removed params from connections/configuration.yaml:
**schema_change**
**notify_schema_changes**
**non_breaking_changes_preference**
**geography**

```
octavia apply
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this on my install and get an error: